# How can I write this statement in Javascript where ECMA Script is not supported?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write this statement in simple javascript where import is not supported..

import IconAlignLeft from 'quill/assets/icons/align-left.svg';

Comment: how do you mean in simple javascript? `const IconAlignLeft = 'quill/assets/icons/align-left.svg'`, or simple reference the image directly `<img src="quill/assets/icons/align-left.svg" />`

Comment: Your title is a bit...confusing. JavaScript is the usual name people use for the language that is known formally as ECMAScript. (It's also the name of Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript, which is why ECMAScript is called ECMAScript, there were licensing issues back when the standard was being created. But usually when people say "JavaScript" what they mean is "ECMAScript," not "Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript." [When they **do** want to say that, they say SpiderMonkey.])

Comment: are you using nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't even standard JavaScript. The use of `import` for things that are not JS modules is a feature of some bundlers (such as Webpack — [relevant documentation is here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/)).

There is no direct equivalent in plain JavaScript (in versions with or without support for modules).

The nearest equivalent would be:

```
const IconAlignLeft = "A string containing a URL that points to the SVG";
```

… but you would need to implement your own process for making the image available at the URL you specify.

Comment: This is a real issue with people learning to develop on-top of a framework. The fundamentals of how the end result actually works becomes alien.

Comment: relevant: [import assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) are currently stage 3